# Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have installed Hadoop and able to access localhost Hadoop interface. When I try to upload files the interface gives me the error "Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error".

Comment: You should look at the logs of the datanode/namenode to find what the actual error is

Answer (score 0):

I typically recommend not using the web interface to upload files

If you want to "properly" upload data to HDFS, use `hadoop fs -put` in the terminal